# Rmarkdown is printing the latex code in the knited PDF

Tags: pdf, latex, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I am running in an odd result. I have inserted a number of tables in my document in Rmarkdown. This is the YAML:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2
    number_sections: true
header-includes:
 \usepackage{float}
 \floatplacement{figure}{H}
 \floatplacement{table}{H}
---
```

And the first chunk:

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,
                      fig.pos = "H",
                      fig.width=8,
                      fig.height=7,
                      tab.pos = "H",
                      collapse = TRUE,
                      message = FALSE,
                      warning = FALSE,
                      comment = "#>"
)

knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file())

options(knitr.kable.NA = "-")
```

The tables are inserted in this manner:

```
kable(tableX, caption = "Caption", booktabs = TRUE) %>% 
  row_spec(0, bold=TRUE) %>% 
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "condensed") %>% 
  column_spec(1, italic = TRUE)
```

Now, most tables are inserted correctly, but there is just one which is printed with the latex code, \begin{table}, then \caption{}, then the table, and at the end \end{table}. How is it possible that one table is being printed in this manner with the code being the same?

Thank you

Comment: It's hard to reproduce the issue without the full code, but I'm suspecting knitr got confused on some latex bits. For further insights, you can add the keep_tex option to inspect the latex that is being generated. Likely, you'll find a `\textbackslash{}begin` there, which results in latex code being shown in pdf output.

Comment: I thought I have included all required code there. The only thing lacking is the header of the chunk and I am only including the option echo=FALSE. But thank you, if I can solve it from there I will accept the answer.

Comment: No, nothing new nor solved.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce your error. What is different about the table that generates the error (or the chunk header, e.g. the caption). Can you create a minimal example (including packages loaded, please) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I can reproduce *some* error when I put a special character (e.g. %) in the caption. Knitr will effetively 'get confused' about the latex code and just prints it as escaped pre-formatted latex code.

Comment: Oh ok. A caption from one valid table: "Sampling effort. SZ: sample size; Mu: number of fish weighted; Otoliths: number of otoliths collected; Stomachs: number of stomachs collected; Me: Median length (cm); Mn: Mean length (cm); Min: minimum length (cm); Max: maximum length (cm); MeanW: mean weight (kg)."

From the one that is giving problems:
"Catch of all species. C(kg): total catch in kg; C(no): total catch in numbers; CPUE: fishing effort in kg of fish catced in 6 hours; NPUE: fishing effort in number of fish catched in 6 hours; % Catch: percentage of the total catch."

Comment: Ok, that was it. I will have to find a way to escape the character or similar. Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the author of rmarkdown Yihui Xie noted [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html#escape-special-characters), you can disable the character-escaping argument in `kable()` to include LaTeX's spacial characters in the table caption, or column/row names, or both. Then you need to manually escape such characters by adding `\\` before each special character.

````
```{r tab1, echo=F}
tableX=data.frame(col1 = "Empty data frame")
kable(
  tableX,
  caption  = "Caption 20\\%",
  booktabs = TRUE,
  escape   = FALSE
  ) |> 
  row_spec(0, bold=TRUE) |>
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "condensed") %>% 
  column_spec(1, italic = TRUE)
```
````

Answer (score 4):

R markdown will produce latex code when the output option is set to `pdf_document` (the latex code can be viewed by selecting the option `keep_tex` and inspecting the produced `.tex` file) or when the output is set to `latex_fragment`.

`knitr::kable` output the full latex output for a table (when in tex mode), but consumes any caption provided literally. The knitr interpreter then consumes the produced latex block. When somewhere in between the `\begin` and `\end` environment statement something illegal is produced (such as a caption with an unescaped `%` in there), the interpreter instead produces escaped latex code.

The valid  code

````
```{r tab1, echo=F}
tableX=data.frame(col1 = "Empty data frame")
kable(tableX, caption = "Caption 20pct", booktabs = TRUE) |> 
  row_spec(0, bold=TRUE) |>
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "condensed") %>% 
  column_spec(1, italic = TRUE)
```
````

produces latex code as expected:

```
\begin{table}

\caption{\label{tab:tab1}Caption 20pct}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{}l}
\toprule
\textbf{col1}\\
\midrule
\em{Empty data frame}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

But when a `%` is added to the caption, the latex code generation breaks. The code block

````
```{r tab1, echo=F}
tableX=data.frame(col1 = "Empty data frame")
kable(tableX, caption = "Caption 20%", booktabs = TRUE) |> 
  row_spec(0, bold=TRUE) |>
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "condensed") %>% 
  column_spec(1, italic = TRUE)
```
````

produces

```
\textbackslash begin\{table\}

\textbackslash caption\{\label{tab:tab1}Caption 20\%\} \centering

\begin{tabular}[t]{>{}l}
\toprule
\textbf{col1}\\
\midrule
\em{Empty data frame}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\textbackslash end\{table\}
```

which just renders in the pdf as literal latex code.